# IText generated PDF is not being displayed in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, itext

IText generated PDF document is not being displayed in Chrome browser

The generated document is being written to the HttpServletResponse object and contentType set to application/pdf but the Chrome browser does not appear to recognize it, no Preview dialog is appearing however, if I run the same application in Firefox browser it works fine

I would expect the Preview to be available in Chrome

Comment: And what *is* displayed instead? Can you save the retrieved data? And which requests go over the net? (Have you checked using e.g. Wireshark yet?) What is your pivotal code? Which versions do you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at this, the problem appears to be in the Git print js plugin, apparently it is a known issue with Chrome. At the moment, nothing appears, the data is in PDF format so is not readily available.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has was found to be in the printJS package, this is a known problem applicable only to Chrome and is being investigated